# Is level 80 the max level?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3, I see people with level 80. I never see anyone passed 80, so is 80 the highest rank that you can obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest rank you can achieve in Modern Warfare 3 is 80, *before prestige*. When you reach level 80, you can still gain exp to continue "levelling up", but instead of reaching level 81, you are given the choice to enter [Prestige Mode](http://au.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/Prestige_Mode).

> When you reach max level, you unlock something known as "Prestige Mode." You have the choice of entering prestige mode and resetting your rank back to 1 and removing all Create-A-Class unlocks and Challenges. A special Prestige Emblem will take the place of your rank emblem, promoting you up a prestige, but lowering you down all levels. You can do this up to ten times for ten prestiges.

[Here](http://au.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/Ranks_and_Unlocks) is a list of all the unlocks and level requirements for levelling up in COD: MW3

Comment: Wow! I noticed that after I entered prestige mode, I gain less match bonus points than before. Is this an effect of going into prestige mode?

Comment: On lower levels you do get much less exp than on higher levels. It's to try and balance the levelling out a bit so the transition doesn't seem so radical.

Comment: That is to say it still requires some effort to level up on lower levels than on higher levels. If it was the same you would probably level up 5 times from one kill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Level 80 is the maximum level in multi player for this game. You can further rank up by starting [prestige mode](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Prestige_Mode), where you level everything again for the sake of an upgraded icon.